# Website design and coding for mobile devices

Tags: iphone, html, ipad, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am trying to develope a website for mobile devices.

I am testing on iphone and ipad at the moment but I have an issue with the ipad.

I have the following code:

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="#">Project Name</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-home icon-white"></i> Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-search pull-right" action="">
          <input type="text" class="search-query span2" placeholder="Search">
        </form>
      </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
  </div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
</div><!-- /.navbar -->
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      test
    </div>
```

On the iphone the text "test" appears correctly positioned under the navbar in both portrait and landscape mode. But on the ipad in horizontal mode the text sits behind the navbar.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Check your `.navbar` if have `z-index`. If have, add higher number and test. If don't have, add something like `z-index:9999`. And do the same with `.container`, but add `z-index:0;`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Bootstrap docs](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navbar) when you use 'navbar-fixed-top'..

> "*Add .navbar-fixed-top and remember to account for the hidden area
>   underneath it by adding at least 40px padding to the . Be sure
>   to add this after the core Bootstrap CSS and before the optional
>   responsive CSS.*"

So you can either include your bootstrap-responsive.css after the body padding CSS like they do on the example (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/starter-template.html)

```
body {padding-top:40px}
```

Or use @media query to adjust the body for smaller screens (phone,tablet)

```
@media (min-width: 979px) {
    body {
        margin-top:40px;
    }
}
```

**Demo using the @media query**: http://bootply.com/60781